# Are these graphics cards (PCI-E vs. PCI Express) interchangeable?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, pci

I'm not sure if I'm on the right Stack Exchange site but I figured I'd try here. I'm fairly new to PC building so I need a bit of help.

The graphics card in my PCI is a [GeForce GTX 760](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications) which has a PCI Express 3.0 connection.

I want to upgrade to a [AMD Radeon RX 580 GTX XXX Edition](http://xfxforce.com/en-us/products/amd-radeon-rx-500-series/rx-580-gts-8gb-dd-rx-580p8dfd6) which has a PCI-E connection.

From what I've read these connections are the same so it should fit, but I want to be certain before making my purchase.

Comment: yes, it will work

Comment: Yes, PCI-E is PCI Express. The plug is the same. They are different cards so you will need to uninstall the drivers for one and install drivers for the other, but that's pretty normal when changing hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can change **GeForce GTX 760** for **AMD Radeon RX 580 GTX XXX Edition**

...from AMD specs:

```
Requirements:
External Power                       1x 8-pins
Minimum Power Supply Requirement     500 watt
XFX Recommended Power Supply XFX     550W PSU
Card Dimension (cm)                  27 x 12.4 x 4
Card Dimension (inch)                10.63 x 4.88 x 1.57
```

---

...from NVIDIA specs:

```
Requirements:
Supplementary Power Connectors       Two 6-pin
Minimum Recommended System Power     500 watt
Height                               4.376 inches (11.11 cm)
Length                               9.5 inches (24.13 cm)
Width                                Dual-slot
```

---

**PCI-E** = **PCI Express**